# NameError: throwing error as name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python, self

```
class Account():

    def __init__(self,owner,balance):
        self.owner = owner
        self.balance = balance

    def __str__(self):
        return "Account owner : {}\nAccount balance: {}".format(self.owner,self.balance)


    def deposit(amount):
        print ("How much you want to deposit")
        amount = int(input())
        self.balance = (balance) + (amount)
        return "Deposit Accepted\nThe new balance is {}".format(self.balance)


    def withdraw(amount):
        if (self.balance >= amount):
            self.balance = self.balance - amount
            return "Withdrawal Accepted\nThe new balance is {}".format(self.balance)
        else:
            return "Insufficient funds!!"


Account_1 = Account("sammy",500)
print(Account_1)
Account_1.owner
Account_1.balance
Account_1.deposit()
Account_1.withdraw(650)
Account_1.withdraw(300)
```

while executing this code i am getting error as "NameError: name 'self' is not defined"
i dont understand why i a getting this error since 'self' is used as 'self reference'for a class and i've done it already.

this code is just a simple problem which i got to solve while studying classes and methods.

Answer (score 2):

`self` should be the first argument to any method in a class that uses `self` (e.g. `self.balance`), so your `withdraw` and `deposit` methods are missing a `self`:

```
def deposit(self,amount):
    print ("How much you want to deposit")
    amount = int(input())
    self.balance += amount
    return "Deposit Accepted\nThe new balance is {}".format(self.balance)


def withdraw(self,amount):
    if (self.balance >= amount):
        self.balance = self.balance - amount
        return "Withdrawal Accepted\nThe new balance is {}".format(self.balance)
    else:
        return "Insufficient funds!!"
```

Note that you're missing the amount in your `self.deposit()` statement. There's also a missing `self` in `self.balance` in your `deposit` method.

Comment: yeah, i got it up and running now.
Wasn't knowing that self need to be the first method. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

deposit and withdraw are member functions. So member functions should have first argument as self. 
Then deposit function do not need an argument in the function definition. Here is the corrected code. Also it would be helpful if you post the stack trace for the error. That would help to zero in on the issue fast.

```
class Account():

def __init__(self,owner,balance):
    self.owner = owner
    self.balance = balance

def __str__(self):
    return "Account owner : {}\nAccount balance: {}".format(self.owner,self.balance)


def deposit(self):
    print ("How much you want to deposit")
    amount = int(input())
    self.balance = self.balance + amount
    return "Deposit Accepted\nThe new balance is {}".format(self.balance)


def withdraw(self, amount):
    if (self.balance >= amount):
        self.balance = self.balance - amount
        return "Withdrawal Accepted\nThe new balance is {}".format(self.balance)
    else:
        return "Insufficient funds!!"
```

Account_1 = Account("sammy",500)
print(Account_1)
Account_1.owner
Account_1.balance
Account_1.deposit()
Account_1.withdraw(650)
Account_1.withdraw(300)